# How to achieve 01/Jan/2000 format in android datepicker

Tags: android, datepicker, date-format

I am trying to achieve date format in 01/Jan/2000  in android datepicker, For this I wrote following code:

```
    alist.add(0, "Jan");
    alist.add(1, "Feb");
    alist.add(2, "Mar");
    alist.add(3, "Apr");
    alist.add(4, "May");
    alist.add(5, "Jun");
    alist.add(6, "Jul");
    alist.add(7, "Aug");
    alist.add(8, "Sep");
    alist.add(9, "Oct");
    alist.add(10, "Nov");
    alist.add(11, "Dec");

 Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
int mYear, mMonth = 0, mDay;
  String arr[] = dob.split("-");
        mYear = Integer.parseInt(arr[2].trim());
        try {
            mMonth = Integer.parseInt(arr[1].trim()) - 1;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        mDay = Integer.parseInt(arr[0].trim());
    } else {
        mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }
    final DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(ProfileActivity.this, R.style.datepicker, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
            int month = selectedmonth + 1;
            String formattedDayOfMonth = "";
            String newmonth = "";
            if (DateHelper.checkPastDate(selectedday + "-" + selectedmonth + "-" + selectedyear)) {
                if (selectedday < 10) {
                    formattedDayOfMonth = "0" + String.valueOf(selectedday);
                } else
                    formattedDayOfMonth =  String.valueOf(selectedday);

                for (int i = 0; i < alist.size(); i++) {
                    if (selectedmonth == i) {
                        newmonth = (String) alist.get(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                changeDOB.setText(formattedDayOfMonth + "-" + newmonth + "-" + selectedyear);
                user.setDob((selectedday + "-" + selectedmonth + "-" + selectedyear));
            } else {
                getApp().showToast("please select valid date");
            }
        }
    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    mDatePicker.setTitle("Select date");
    mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mDatePicker.show();
}
```

But here, I am Getting following Exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "Jan"
```

on Line:

```
 mMonth = Integer.parseInt(arr[1].trim()) - 1;
```

Please Help  me Out To solve this. Thank you.

Comment: What is the possible value of 'dob' ??

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

                DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                                                            String month = "", day = "";
                                                                            if (monthOfYear < 10) {
                                                                                month = "0" + (monthOfYear + 1);
                                                                            } else {
                                                                                month = String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1);
                                                                            }

                                                                            if (dayOfMonth < 10) {
                                                                                day = "0" + dayOfMonth;
                                                                            } else {
                                                                                day = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                                                                            }

                                                                            String date = year + "/" + (month) + "/" + (day);
                                                                            edAddnewsMissingdate.setText(date);
                                                                        }
                                                                    }, now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
                dpd.setMaxDate(Calendar.getInstance());
                break;
```

Comment: must include 

    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go through [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation. After that the date format you are searching for is **dd/MMM/yyyy**

Answer (score 0):

Use **SimpleDateFormat** to format and parse the date. This way you can easily save the date from Calendar in the format you want and later you can convert it back to Calendar object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to get same format

```
et1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                int y = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+4;
                int m = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)-2;
                int d = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                final String[] MONTH = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

                DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                    int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                String erg = "";
                                erg = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                                erg += "." + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1);
                                erg += "." + year;

                                ((TextView) et1).setText(erg);

                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html%22Calendar%22) and [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html%22SimpleDateFormat%22) to format the date.

I have tested the following code and it works to give the desired format.

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.set(selectedyear, selectedmonth, selectedday);

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
dateFormat.setCalendar(cal);
String date = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

You can update your code as follows to set the DOB:

```
final DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(ProfileActivity.this, R.style.datepicker, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
            int month = selectedmonth + 1;
            String formattedDayOfMonth = "";
            String newmonth = "";
            if (DateHelper.checkPastDate(selectedday + "-" + selectedmonth + "-" + selectedyear)) {
                Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                cal.set(selectedyear, selectedmonth, selectedday);

                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
                dateFormat.setCalendar(cal);

                user.setDob(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
            } else {
                getApp().showToast("please select valid date");
            }
        }
    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
```